# Is try-catch block really needed in MVC application, when we have Exception Filters in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception

We have try catch block for error handling, But in case of MVC we have exception filters. In such case we can handle errors at filter level. i.e. by using exception filters.

So again writing try-catch block at method level is really needed?

Comment: exeption filters are part of mvc. try/catch are part of the language...

Answer (score 1):

MVC has exception filter in order to display error pages, rather than allowing the exception to bubble up to IIS (i.e. crashing the whole app), where you'd get the simple (and ugly) generic error pages.

However, the idea is that uncaught exceptions should actually be a rarity. For the most part, you don't actually *want* to return a 500 error page, even if it's a "pretty" error page. Catching the exceptions in your code allows you to do *defensive coding*. In other words, you can try to handle and recover from those exceptions, such that your site still works, and at the worst, you give specific and guided messages to the user regarding how to avoid the error.

Long and short, yes, still important to use try-catch blocks, and I'd argue even *crucial*. Unless, you specifically mean to return a 500 error (there are some occasions, particular in APIs, where that might be desirable), you should catch and handle every exception yourself.